# How can we extract rows with sequential values in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I wanna select only rows with three or more sequential values.

| num1 | num2 | num3 | num4 | num5 | num6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 9 | 13 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| 5 | 8 | 11 | 17 | 21 | 24 |

[Result]

| num1 | num2 | num3 | num4 | num5 | num6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 9 | 13 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |

Is there an easy way using pandas or numpy?

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: How many rows and columns are in real data?

Answer (score 5):

Get differencies per rows by [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html), compare for `1` with [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), count `True`s by `sum` and compare if greater or equal by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html):

```
df1 = df[df.diff(axis=1).eq(1).sum(axis=1).ge(3)]
```

EDIT: You can count consecutive `1` of differencies by `cumulative sum`, then get maximal values and compare for greater or equal:

```
print (df)
   num1  num2  num3  num4  num5  num6
0     1     2     4     5     8     9
1     3     7     8     9    10    11
2     9    13    21    22    23    24
3     5     8    11    17    21    24

df1 = df.diff(axis=1)
m = df1.eq(1)
b = m.cumsum(axis=1)
mask = b.sub(b.mask(m).ffill(axis=1).fillna(0)).max(axis=1).ge(3)
df2 = df[mask]
print (df2)
   num1  num2  num3  num4  num5  num6
1     3     7     8     9    10    11
2     9    13    21    22    23    24
```

**Details**:

```
print (b.sub(b.mask(m).ffill(axis=1).fillna(0)))
   num1  num2  num3  num4  num5  num6
0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
1   0.0   0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
2   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0
3   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Performance (best test in real data), but generally `rolling` here is bottleneck:

```
#40k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [82]: %%timeit
    ...: df1 = df.diff(axis=1)
    ...: m = df1.eq(1)
    ...: b = m.cumsum(axis=1)
    ...: mask = b.sub(b.mask(m).ffill(axis=1).fillna(0)).max(axis=1).ge(3)
    ...: df[mask]
    ...: 
    ...: 
35.6 ms ± 475 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


In [83]: %%timeit
    ...: df[df.diff(axis=1).eq(1).T.rolling(window=N).sum().ge(N).any()]
    ...: 
2.79 s ± 63.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: thank you :) I think I still lack a lot of things. (Laughs)

Comment: @jezrael try axis=1 in your concat, you'll get 2s for your solution and 10ms for mine, "real data" is quite subjective ;)

Comment: @mozway - good point, I ask in comments under question

Answer (score 5):

IIUC, compute a [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) on the columns, select the ones equal to 1 (i.e. consecutive values) (with [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)) and determine if there are any 3 consecutive values with [`rolling.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sum.html). Use the produced Series to perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
N=3
df[df.diff(axis=1).eq(1).T.rolling(window=N).sum().ge(N).any()]
```

output:

```
   num1  num2  num3  num4  num5  num6
0     1     2     3     4     5     6
1     3     7     8     9    10    11
2     9    13    21    22    23    24
```

intermediate count of consecutive values:

```
>>> df.diff(axis=1).eq(1).T.rolling(window=3).sum()

        0    1    2    3
num1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
num2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
num3  2.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
num4  3.0  2.0  1.0  0.0
num5  3.0  3.0  2.0  0.0
num6  3.0  3.0  3.0  0.0
```

###### previous incorrect answer (common to everyone in this Q/A)

This was only counting the number of successive values, not if they **all are consecutive**. For instance 1-2-4-5-7-8 would count 3 consecutive whereas they are not all consecutive*

```
N = 3
df1 = df[df.diff(axis=1).eq(1).sum(axis=1).ge(N)]
```

Comment: @mozway nice work.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
df = df[df.diff(axis=1).eq(1).sum(axis=1).ge(3)]
```

Comment: This answer is wrong as it will say that `{ 'num1':1, 'num2':2, 'num3':4, 'num4':5, 'num5':8, 'num6':9}` has 3 sequential values

Comment: @Nick but he already wants the row if it contains 3 or more sequential values so where is the wrong thing.

Comment: `1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9` does not contain 3 or more sequential values